# Mass renaming linkages in a FLA

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have an AS3 based FLA that, for various reasons, needs nearly all of the linkages in the library reworked (need to move to a different package namespace).  This particular FLA is pretty big, so doing this by hand would be rather tedious.

What is the best way to handle this?

I have considered saving out the FLA as an XFL, and just hand editing all of the XML files in the `LIBRARY` folder, and then saving out as FLA.  Has anyone tried this?  I have never worked with XFL files before, so I don't know what quirks I may run across.

Are there any existing JSFL scripts that handle this?

Thanks.

EDIT:

My problem has to do with loading SWFs and class conflicts because of multiple SWFs using the same package namespace.  Without getting into too many details, I know about [ApplicationDomain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html) and [LoaderContext](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html).  I am currently loading into a new ApplicationDomain, but that isn't an ideal situation and is causing grief that won't be maintainable in the long run.

Comment: This is why we make a config file.

Comment: @The_asMan Can you clarify what you mean?  I am having class conflicts when loading one SWF into another.  I need to repackage one of the SWFs to avoid the conflicts.  I don't see how a config file would help with class namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to Flash IDE today but you can easily adapt my 
script to do what you want : 
[Automated importing/renaming of Flash assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030997/automated-importing-)
renaming-of-flash-assets/6031965#6031965

There is an easy way to find what Jsfl functions you have to use :

1. Open History panel  (Window > Other Panels > History)
2. Make one linkage renaming
3. Copy history to jsfl and adapt code

Comment: Thanks.  This is a big headstart.